# PHP : Class Extends

Tags: php

I have made some example code to explain my question:

```
class Core {
   public $test = null;
   public function __construct(){
       $this->test = "hi";
   }
}

$data = new Core;

class Extension extends Core {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->test = "hello";
    }
}

$data->ext = new Extension;

echo $data->test . "<br />";
echo $data->ext->test;
```

Which outputs as:

> hi 
>  hello

My question is hard to explain but I am just wondering if there was a way to overwrite the $test variable in the parent class within the child class so:

`echo $this->test;` would output "hello" since it changed in the child class.

Is there a way of doing this or can the child not access/change the parent variables?

Comment: Then a `static` variable should work for you

Comment: Could you explain how to do this or possibly reference something I could look at? Thank-you @codeHeart or would it just be `public static $test = null;` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php, the second example should help you

Comment: That hits the nail on the head, I think I should start using `static` on connections then... Oh god. Thanks @codeHeart Put an answer if you like, I need to mark something

Comment: Hehe, Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `static` property for your use case.

Check here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php, the second example should help you

Comment: Quick question, the manual doesn't explain if static variables can be altered because I am receiving an error when trying to change it: https://gyazo.com/a86a281c7615f782cd2a47828ea24097

Comment: Yes the way to access the variable is also different you need to use `Classname::$variableName` instead of `$instance->variableName`, check the example on how to use.

Comment: What about to change its content? `self::test = "hi";` returns an error: 
FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '=' on line number 6 :/

Comment: you have to use the `$` in front of the variable name, so it would be `self::$test = "hi"`

Comment: Thank-you for this! You've just broke my current limitation to what I was trying to achieve! Thanks! @codeHeart